# Parse json using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I receive a json file from a python server, which I try to parse using ajax to display the values according to the categories(e.g.data_provider,census) in separate drop down menus  .But i constantly get the following error:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"data_provider":"census","data_year":"2010","data_series":"sf1","tb_name":"h1","summ_level":"160"},{"data_provider":"census","data_year":"2010","data_series":"sf1","tb_name":"p1","summ_level":"050"}]

Kindly help me out ! Below is the code I wrote.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function codeAddress() {
        var ajax = $.ajax({
            //data : params,
            type : "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "json",
            //jsonp: "callback",
            //callbackParameter: "callback",
            //contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            url : "http://0.0.0.0:8080/"

        });

        ajax.done(function() {
            var response=ajax.responseText;
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response);


            $(json).each(function(i,val){
                $.each(val,function(k,v){
                    console.log(k+" : "+ v);
                });
            });
        });

        ajax.fail(function() {
            alert("fail");
        });


        ajax.always(function() {
           alert("done");
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body id="b1" onload="codeAddress();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Given your JSON and your code (but changing the URL to one where I've hosted the JSON), [I can't reproduce the problem](http://jsbin.com/kefitesu/1/).

Comment: @Quentin Is it possible that an unescaped UTF control character is in the string?

Comment: @crush — Or any invisible character. That's quite a plausible reason for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're setting `datatype` to `json`, I'd guess you do not need to parse the JSON yourself. Please note that the parsed response is provided in the `done` method's first argument, see this example from the jQuery docs:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
})
.done(function( data ) {
  console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
});
```

Comment: It is true that the OP doesn't need to parse the response themselves, but since they are getting the raw `responseText` and parsing that, doing so won't cause a problem.

Comment: Yep, I think this is the case: @user2284140 is trying to parse an already parsed JSON so is trying to parse a Hash.

Comment: So, I can directly use the json I receive within the variable response by ajax.responseText and use it to index the values ?

Comment: @fguillen — No, as I said, he is accessing `responseText` and not the parsed data from the JSON.

Comment: When applying `JSON.parse` twice, I get the error: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o "`. This isn't exactly the same error the OP is getting.

Comment: @crush — It isn't what the OP is doing in the question either.

Comment: @Quentin Right. Just adding more evidence to your first comment since it seemed to breeze right over some of these guys head.

Comment: @user2284140 - you should not use `ajax.responseText` at all. Instead, add an argument `data` to the `done` function (see example above), and edit your `each` call to use `data` instead of `json`.

Comment: I did that...still the same problem

Comment: Here is the code snippet:
ajax.done(function(data) {
                //var response=ajax.responseText;
                //var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response);


                $(data).each(function(i,val){
                    $.each(val,function(k,v){
                        console.log(k+" : "+ v);
                    });
                });
            });

Comment: Of course not, the `/echo/json` URL I used returns an empty json response (i.e. `[]`). I can only load JSON from the same domain as the javascript (i.e. jsfiddle.net in this case, or in your case, 0.0.0.0:8080). In every other case the browser will prevent you from fetching the JSON (If you want to do that, you should look at JSONP).

Comment: But, I cannot understand one thing..I am getting the json string...the problem lies in the parsing right?? I copy pasted your exact code...only replacing the url with mine...still the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jQuery, just let them do the grunt work for you!

```
$.getJSON("http://0.0.0.0:8080/", function(json){
// do your JSON work here
});
```

If for whatever reason you can't use $.getJSON, in your $.ajax request, set a `success` callback function like the one i have over here.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Also `$.getJSON` cannot be used in every situation where you need `JSON` returned.

Comment: How? This is the simple solution to the problem.

Comment: I think this is a valid answer, or at least doesn't deserve a -1 :/

Comment: I think nearly every situation. In any case, `datatype: 'json'` should have them parse it.

Comment: If this solves the problem, what is it about the existing code that causes the problem?

Comment: @Quentin I'm not quite sure what's causing the problem, but this should avoid it.

Comment: There are numerous reasons why `$.getJSON` isn't always an option for receiving `JSON`. For example, how would you set `crossDomain: true` with `$.getJSON`? (which is in the author's code)

Comment: Alright, i see your point. But `datatype: 'json'` should work nonetheless.

Comment: @Scimonster It should, but it's not. Hence, why the guy asked the question.

Comment: @crush It should, but he's not using the success callback and JSON parsing features.

Comment: @Scimonster There's nothing wrong with what he's doing. It might not be ideal, but it certainly doesn't appear to be erroneous.

Comment: @crush Well, if it's not working, something must be erroneous, wouldn't you say? ;)

Comment: @Scimonster Certainly something is erroneous. It doesn't appear to be the code he has posted, though. As Quentin demonstrated, the above code works fine. It's most likely his data source that is the problem here.